# C#: Choosing operator depending on boolean value (in one line)

Tags: c#, operators

I'm trying to get away with a slick one liner as I feel it is probably possible.

I'll put my code below and then try to explain a little more what I'm trying to achieve.

```
        for (int p = 0; p < 2; p++)
        {
            foreach (string player in players[p])
            {
                if (PlayerSkills[player].streak_count *>* 0) //This line
                    PlayerSkills[player].streak_count++;
                else
                    PlayerSkills[player].streak_count = 0;
            }
        }
```

*(p==0 ? >:<) the comparison operator is chosen depending on p.

Of course what I've written is rubbish. But basically I want to use >0 when p==0, and <0 when p>>0. Is there a nice way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you write it in actual valid code first so it's easier to see the intent? Right now I'm just looking at a bunch of emoticons

Comment: Sorry, the idea was that the (p==0 ? >:<) would choose the appropriate operator, I'll update it. Though I think one of the answers may be what I was looking for.

Comment: Don't write a "slick one liner" if the end result is hard to read. Readability is far more important than the code fitting on one line.

Comment: I think that's good advice, I'll just use multiple statements so that in a month's time I don't get lost in the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you should use what is most readable, even if it is not as consice.  That said...

```
// Invert the count for all but the first player and check for a positive number
if (PlayerSkills[player].streak_count * (p==0 ? 1 : -1) > 0)
```

Comment: +1 Very clever (and shorter than mine) not the most readable (as you noted). Without a lot of thinking I would have no idea what that did.

Comment: It is what I am looking for since 5 minutes!

Comment: This is actually quite straightforward, if not the most readable.

Comment: Really nice, this is exactly what I was looking for, elegant :).

That said, I will follow the advice of others and just use a couple simpler statements to save me hassle later.

Comment: @user3477950: "readable" is a very relative notion. Once you have the habit of this kind of structure, reading it is easy and fast. As an example of the opposite, the verbosity of a code don't help me to understand it faster, and can go up to parasitize the main information.

Comment: Ummm... @user3477950 I'm pretty sure Casimir was *agreeing* with you. And even if not, was being quite polite.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about slick, but the following and/or combination *is* one line:

```
if ((p == 0 && PlayerSkills[player].streak_count > 0)
     || PlayerSkills[player].streak_count < 0)
...
```

This will only ever do the array index once (due to the p==0 condition occurring first) and so is equivalent to the "ternary" you wrote (albeit a bit more verbose).

Comment: Nope!  Wrapped in my browser ;)

Comment: @adv12, easy solution: Make your browser wider :) (note that I put it on two lines for readability, but it really is one statement)

Answer (score 0):

`p > 0 ? whenGreaterThanZero : whenZeroOrLess ;`

E.g.

`int p = 1; bool test =  p > 0 ? true : false ;`

Lets `test` = `True`

Comment: Could you provide a more complete sample? I don't think I understand this one.

Comment: That helps... It would be nice if it was in the context given. That said, I'll remove my downvote.